# What value have int fields in struct not initialized yet?

Tags: c, struct, char, int

In the code:
...

```
 #define MAXELEMNTS 100

 struct book
 {
     int number;
     char name[31];
     char author[31];
     int year;
     char publisher[31];
 };

 struct book bkStruct[MAXELEMENTS];
```

...

Are the integer fields (number and year) initialized to 0 by default when the other char fields are initialized but not these two? Or do they have god-knows-what value? In my experience they do have value = 0, but I am not sure is this general rule so I must be sure!

Best regards,
Papo

Comment: It depends, you did not provide enough information for an answer.

Comment: It depends on whether `bkStruct` has automatic or static storage duration.

Comment: Have a look at initialization of objects when using `new`. They also apply to initialization of objects on the stack. http://stackoverflow.com/a/620402/434551

Comment: @RSahu: OP tagged `c` language, not `c++`. There is no `new` keyword in `c` language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C there is no such thing as "partial initialization".
If a struct is initialized by specifying a value for a single member, all the other members are automagically initialized (to `0` of the proper kind).

```
struct book
{
    int number;
    char name[31];
    char author[31];
    int year;
    char publisher[31];
};

struct book book1; // no initialization
struct book book2 = { .author = "pmg" }; // initialization of ALL of book2

struct book bkStruct1[MAXELEMENTS]; // uninitialized array
struct book bkStruct2[MAXELEMENTS] = {0}; // initialized array
                                          // (every member of every element)
```

<sub>Note: some implementations may complain about missing braces on the perfectly legal array initialization. That is a problem with those implementations.</sub>

Comment: I agree that complaining about `{0}` is a problem. It's not a bug, though, or at least not a failure to conform to the standard -- as long as it's a warning and not a fatal error.

Comment: If `struct book book1;` occurs outside a function, is it not initialized with all bits zero?

Comment: @chux: It's initialized to *zero* (defined recursively down to `0` for integers, `0.0` for floating-point, and `NULL` for pointers), which may or may not be represented as all bits zero (though it very probably is).

Answer (score 3):

If you define an object with an initializer, it's initialized to the specified value. If you only specify values for some members, the others are initialized to zero (meaning `0` for integers (including characters), `0.0` for floating-point values, and `NULL` for pointers).

If you define an object without an initializer, all members are implicitly initialized to zero *if* the object has static storage duration, i.e., if it's defined outside any function or if it's defined with the `static` keyword.

An object defined inside a function without the `static` keyword has *automatic storage duration*. Such objects, if not explicitly initialized, start off with garbage values. (If you happen to see such objects seemingly initialized to zero, remember that zero can be just as much a garbage value as anything else.)

You asked:

> Are the integer fields (number and year) initialized to 0 by default
>   when the other char fields are initialized but not these two?

but the code in your question doesn't initialize the `char[]` fields. See [pmg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23479089/827263), which shows some good examples, but doesn't currently mention the `static` vs. automatic distinction.

Answer (score -1):

to be on safe side you should intialize your varibales to 0 yourself depending upon compiler it might pick garbage value as well

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.