# Unsigned int field of struct got automatically initialized?

Tags: c, struct

Does C guarantees that an unsigned integer field inside a struct gets initialized to zero? In my system, it seems it does (or I am very "lucky"(actually unlucky)).

In code words, what will happen in the following scenario?

```
struct node {
  unsigned int rec_size;
};

struct node node;
// what is the value of node.rec_size? Undefined or 0?
```

Relevant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478693/what-value-have-int-fields-in-struct-not-initialized-yet), but not the same, since in my example, there is only one field and no initialization.

Comment: Depends. Where did you put it?

Comment: Well, think about that at some time of your life you didn't know about it too. Maybe I am in this case and it's OK. :) Yeah I got that where I put it makes the difference. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is, it depends on the storage-class:

If it is `_Thread_local` or `static`, it is guaranteed to be zeroed.

If it is `auto` or dynamic storage, no initialization takes place.

> #### 6.7.9 Initialization
>
> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>     and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>     rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

BTW: Zero-initialization in C++ is equivalent to those rules for static/thread-local objects.

Comment: Yes, C has an `auto` keyword. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192547/where-is-the-c-auto-keyword-used

Comment: `auto` is the keyword (introduced for symmetry at the beginning of time), marking auto-storage-class objects (function-local, no explicit storage-class aka stack-allocated). And yes, in C++11 they finally got around to remove those semantics in C++ replace them with type-deduction-semantics (Stroustroup already wanted to do that in C-with-classes ages ago).

Comment: @wolfPack88: Ah, to be young!!

Answer (score 5):

No, the value is undetermined.

Value will be 0 only if the variable is static or global.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because of the reference.